# The most optimal solution for sending Java Source Code to Google App Engine via Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: javascript, java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing an application which needs to accept Java Source code from the client via the Google Cloud Endpoints, and then the Google App Engine would work on it. The simplest solution was to send the Java Source Code as a `String` from the JavaScript client and make an endpoint which accepts the `String`. However a `GET` request more than 2kB is giving errors and Source Codes can be (and are generally often) far larger than 2kB.

It will be important to note here that minification of the code is not allowed.

Then what should be the  best way to achieve so?

An advanced thanks for trying to solve my issue.

Comment: "However GET/POST request can handle not more than 2kB of data" where did you read that? (GET requests are indeed limited since you can only put data into the url and urls have a limit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request).

Comment: @zapl edited my mistake out, but the problem remains a Get request larger than 2kB is not working

Comment: Ok, then why not use post?

Comment: POST request is causing 413 error on large source size.

Comment: You're probably using it wrong then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187807/995891

Comment: Please try it out at [link](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://pseudogen-2016.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/pseudoGen/v1/pseudoGen.pseudo) and enter a Java Source Code at source tab

Comment: This is the code I used:`@ApiMethod(name = "pseudo", path = "pseudo", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST) public PseudoCon getPseudoCode(@Named("source")String source){` what's wrong in it? It accepts the source code and not some URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using it wrong. `@Named` parameters become part of the url (like `http://server.com/api?source=Java+source+here.`), and that has the same limitations as a GET request.

You can encapsulate your data in a pojo and add it as method parameter. For example

```
@Api(name = "myApi", version = "v1")
public class MyApi {

    public static class PseudoCon {
        public String foo;
    }

    public static class SourceContainer {
        public String source;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "pseudo", path = "pseudo", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
    public PseudoCon getPseudoCode(SourceContainer sourceContainer){
        String source = sourceContainer.source;
        PseudoCon result = new PseudoCon();
        result.foo = source.substring(0, 1);
        return result;
    }
}
```

That allows for a proper POST with a request body:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/myApi/v1/pseudo

{
 "source": "Java source here."
}
```

(source becomes encapsulated in a json object)

With reply

```
200 OK
{
 "foo": "J"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @zapl I wish I could up-vote your answer but this question killed my reputation for upvoting

Comment: @SwagatoChatterjee np, I have more than I need. PS: you'll get less downvotes when you don't use sort of rude sounding requests with "please refrain from .." as well as asking for "The most optimal solution" :)

Comment: thanks for teaching me some etiquette.